# How do I scale various sizes of Sprites size in an Image?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a bunch of sprites that are in various heights and widths.  I want to get them to scale so that that they aren't stretched.

Right now every image fills the space avaialable.

```
public GameObject AnimationArea;
private float animationHeightBase;
private float animationWidthBase;

Image positionImage;
```

I start by getting the base size of the area I want the image to appear.

```
void Start()
{
    RectTransform rt = (RectTransform)AnimationArea.transform;
    animationHeightBase = rt.rect.height;
    animationWidthBase = rt.rect.width;
}
```

This part selects the image that will show up

```
void WhichSideUp()
{
    switch (sideUp)
    {
        case 6:
            height = imageSide5.bounds.size.y;
            width = imageSide5.bounds.size.x;
            positionImage.sprite = imageSide5; // Sprite to Image
            Resize(); //Set the size of the image
            break;
        case 5:
            height = imageSide4.bounds.size.y;
            width = imageSide4.bounds.size.x;
            positionImage.sprite = imageSide4; // Sprite to Image
            Resize(); //Set the size of the image
            break;
        case 4:
            SAME
        case 3:
            SAME
        case 2:
            SAME
        case 1:
            SAME
        default:
            break;
    }
```

I am trying to resize the image based on if the height is larger than the width or width > height.

```
void Resize()
{
    float imgScalex;
    float imgScaley;

    if(height > width)
    {
        float ratio = width / height;
         imgScalex = (animationHeightBase * ratio);
         imgScaley = animationHeightBase;
    } else
    {
        float ratio = height / width;
        imgScalex = animationWidthBase;
        imgScaley = (animationWidthBase * ratio);
    }

    positionImage = new Vector2(imgScalex, imgScaley);  //this is where I am failing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a work around and change the code up a bit.  I ended up changing the scale of the image verse changing the size.  It seems to be working pretty good.  I also had to play with the scale so that it would look good.

```
void Resize()
{
    float imgScalex;
    float imgScaley;
    if(height > width)
    {
        float ratio = width / height;         
        imgScaley = 1;
        imgScalex = ratio * .75f;  /added the .75 because it wasn't scaling properly
    } else
    {
        float ratio = height / width;   
        imgScaley = ratio * 1.5f; /added the 1.5 because it wasn't scaling properly
        imgScalex = 1;
    }
    positionImage.transform.localScale = new Vector2(imgScalex, imgScaley);
```

Comment: If you change the scale, you shouldn't take care of the aspect ratio, so just put (0.5,0.5) and it will be half in both width and height with the same aspect ratio. That * .75f and * 1.5f has no sense.